# How to tell if a function is surjective from its graph

Tags: functions

I am trying to figure out a way to check a function if it is surjective from the graph of the function. I know that we can know about injective functions by drawing a line parallel to x-axis.
I am new to this topic and this site as well. Is there any way to check if the range of the function is equal to the codomain?

Comment: I am not that fluent in English. Sorry if something is wrong in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all line parallel to X-axis ( assuming codomain is whole Y axis) intersect with  graph then function is surjective.

Answer (score 0):

Project the graph onto the $y$-axis and see whether the projection is the whole codomain (=surjective) or a propert part of it (=not surjective)

Comment: Is y=tanx a bijective function? The function is from R to R.

Comment: When talking about functions you should always specify domain and codomain, otherwise such questions can't be answered.

Comment: If you project every point of the graph to the $y$-axis you get the real line, so it is surjective